Azure api management service fails to authorize call to web app API
I'm trying to set up an Azure API Management Service with one backend API hosted in an Azure web app. APIM is supposed to authenticate against the Web App with the help of a service principal.
I activated the system assigned managed identity of APIM and of the Web App and adapted the APIM inbound policy:
<inbound>
    <authentication-managed-identity resource="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" /> 
    <base />
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="xxxxxxxxxx" />
</inbound>
 

The UID for the authentication-managed-identiy resource I got from the Authentication tab of the Web App as can be seen in the picture.

I also added the managed identiy of the APIM as Contributor to the WebApp.
However, when I test my API in APIM, I get a 403 Forbidden
If I remove the line <authentication-managed-identity resource="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
I get a 401 Unauthorized
I think this tells me, that the authentication is working, but the apim managed identity has no access rights to the API so the authorization fails.
Can anybody tell me, how I can grant the APIM managed identity the correct access rights to my Web App API?
PS If I remove access restrictions to the Web App, I get a 200 OK and the correct output, so the API access in general is working.
Thanks
Simon

You need to enable Authentication in APIM instance instead of Web App then use authentication-managed-identity policy

Not really sure what you mean by that. I have to configure the authentication in the web app, otherwise one could access the api directly (bypassing APIM).
And what do you mean by enable Authentication in APIM? I already use authentication-managed-identity in he policy in APIM.
I thought that I maybe have to expose the api from the web-app in the coresponding app registration of the web app to the enterpirse application of APIM, but this does not work.
Maybe I do not understand you correctly. Could you elaborate, please?
PS It's the first time I use APIM so I'm not really familiar with it

Follow the steps below to get this work-

Create a new Application in Microsoft Entra Id or use an existing one. Use client Id of the registered app in the policy.

<policy>
    <inbound>
    <base />
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="{ClientId of the Entra App}" /> 
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="xxxxxxxxxx" />
    </inbound>
</policy>


Enable System managed Identity in APIM instance.



Look for the Enterprise Application which got created post enabling the system managed identity and then copy the application Id.



Then, configure Authentication in Web App as shown below. Paste the application Id which you have copied in step 3 in allowed client applications field.





By doing the illustrated the steps you can access the Web Apps in APIM.



Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! It solved my problem.
I kinda did all those steps already, but I had an issue with the enterprise application:
When I searched the list of enterprise applications in my EntraID, I cannot see it so I used the Object ID from the managed identity tab of APIM (which I now know is wrong). I was able to search directly for the Object ID and found the enterprise application and was so able to get the application ID. This solved the issue.
Do you maybe know, why the Enterprise Application of APIM does not show up in my Entra id under "All applications"?

@SimonK When you are searching here, you need to search by object id but you are looking here you can search by name
